# Change the base branch commit after the PR is opened

Tags: git, github, version-control

As a part of my workflow I open Work-In-Progress Pull Requests on Github. In the meantime someone merges some changes to the base branch, which don't show in the diff (I'm guessing Github takes HEAD commit of the base branch when the PR is opened)

Is there a way to update the base branch commit in a PR? Essentially, tell Github "Hey, could diff against master HEAD instead of master HEAD^n? "(where n in the commit that was used when the PR was created)

I have tried:

- changing the base branch to something else and go back https://github.com/blog/2224-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request
- Could do `rebase` or `merge` the base branch, but I'd like to avoid that

Comment: Why would you avoid `merge`? According to me that's a clean way to go about it. And resolve any conflicts while merging.

Comment: but there are no conflicts. I'd like to avoid merge to simplify history. my comit, merge to update and another merge to merge to the base branch

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to update the bash branch during a PR is opened. **Github do it automatically**.

When you updated the bash branch before PR is approved, the bash branch will automatically updated when others view the PR, and when the PR is approved, the other branch will merged into the newest bash branch.

The **HEAD is not affected** even though the base branch is updated during a PR. Because the base branch’s change is made by others, in your local repo, you should fetch first and then compare the difference as below,

```
git fetch origin
git checkout basebranch
git diff basebranch origin/basebranch
```

Then you will find the difference. Also you can see the new changes in github pull request Tab, you can find the related commits and the changed files.

Comment: Sure, the problem is that the `diff` shows it and it's confusing for the reviewer (and me as well)

Comment: `diff`will show correctly after you fetch the changes and then compare. I added the detail in my answer.